# can prototype functions access local variables?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I thought that functions created using .prototype were supposed to be able to access local variables. Here is what I'm talking about:

```
function obj() {
    var a = "String";

    this.innerPrint = function() {
        document.write("<p>" + a + "</p>");
    };
}

obj.prototype.outerPrint = function() {
    document.write("<p>" + a + "</p>");
};

var inst = new obj();
inst.innerPrint();
inst.outerPrint();
```

What I thought would happen is that both of these functions would do the same thing. But what actually happened is outerPrint doesn't have access to the variable a. Could someone explain to me how you get locals in a prototype function.

Here is a fiddle running this code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Wryte/mxXzg/

By the way, I want to use prototype functions because then each instantiation of the object doesn't have a copy of the function but they each point to the same one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course not, you cannot access one function's locals from another function *defined outside the first*. It does not matter if the second is defined in the prototype property of the first. Each invocation of your `obj` function defines a *new* local `a` variable, so you cannot avoid having separate copies of the function that needs to access it.

I assume you actually require that variable to be a local and not an instance property, so one possible approach would be to have only a thin local wrapper around your function:

```
function obj() {
    var a = "String";

    this.wrapper = function() { outerPrint.call(this, a); }
    this.innerPrint = function() {
        document.write("<p>" + a + "</p>");
    };
}

function outerPrint(a) {
    document.write("<p>" + a + "</p>");
};
```

Again, I assume you have a more complex function in place of `outerPrint`, so this way you can avoid the duplication of a large function at the expense of duplication of a minimal wrapper. This way you retain the privateness of the `a` variable, while a public getter would allow external code to inspect its value.

**UPDATE:** On @Bergi's remark, I've modified the code to make `outerPrint` a local function in the same scope where the `obj` constructor is defined. No longer being on the prototype, it will not be directly callable for `obj` instances. Note that all of the code will need to be inside a function scope, in order to avoid a global `outerPrint` function.

Comment: If you do things like that, `outerPrint` should not be on the prototype but just some static function floating around in the same scope as `obj`

Answer (score 1):

If you want your variable `a` to be still accessible after the constructor has finished execution, change your code to

```
function obj() {
    this.a = "String";

    this.innerPrint = function() {
        document.write("<p>" + this.a + "</p>");
    };
}

obj.prototype.outerPrint = function() {
    document.write("<p>" + this.a + "</p>");
};
```

Or define a getter if you don't want to provide direct write access :

```
function obj() {
    var a = "String";
    this.getA = function() {
        return a;
    }
    this.innerPrint = function() {
        document.write("<p>" + a + "</p>");
    };
}

obj.prototype.outerPrint = function() {
    document.write("<p>" + this.getA() + "</p>");
};
```

Comment: but what if I don't want 'a' to be accessed publicly?

Comment: See edit : in the second version a can't be written publicly.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare 'a' it's declared in the lexical scope of the obj()-function. All instance variables needs to be prototype'd as well, so insted of `var a` it should be declared as `this.a`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is a *local* variable. Scope rules are not bypassed because of a property named `prototype`.

The variable is accessible only from functions defined inside the constructor; they are called *privileged* because of that. Of course, when those are accessible as public methods you can call them from outside, ie.

```
Obj.prototype.outerPrint = function() {
    this.innerPrint();
};
```

Comment: This is true but a little misleading : [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) isn't just a simple "property named prototype".

Comment: @dystroy: No, it is just that. The property gets its special meaning only when an instance is constructed by the use of the `new` operator.

Comment: Not when declaring/creating the method. The instantiation can happen elsewhere.